# Accuracy of Model dropped gradually every loop

Tags: python, dataframe, neural-network, regression

I have 5 different sets of data and want find evaluation metrics for every set using neural network regression. I realized that the R^2 is dropping every loop in order manner. I'm pretty sure there should be a point that I need to identify, but not sure where in my code.

My code:

```
for sensor, sensorlol, name in zip(sensors, sensorslol, names):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sensor, reference, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    x_trainl, x_testl, y_trainl, y_testl = train_test_split(sensorlol, referencelol, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

    kf=KFold(7, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
    ann=MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=int(node), activation='relu',
                     learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=initl, shuffle=False)
    ann.fit(x_train, y_train)
    m_predictionlol=cross_val_predict(ann, sensorlol, referencelol, cv=kf)
    R2lol=r2_score(referencelol, m_predictionlol)
    MAElol=mean_absolute_error(referencelol, m_predictionlol)
    RMSElol=mean_squared_error(referencelol, m_predictionlol)
    MBElol=np.mean(m_predictionlol-referencelol)
    r_2lol.append(R2lol)
    maelol.append(MAElol)
    rmselol.append(RMSElol)
    mbelol.append(MBElol)
    sumref=np.sum(referencelol)
    probref=referencelol/sumref
    sumtest=np.sum(m_predictionlol)
    probtest=m_predictionlol/sumtest
    KLlol=sum(rel_entr(probtest,probref))
    kllol.append(KLlol)
    del m_predictionlol, sensorlol
dataframe1=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(lst, r_2lol, maelol, rmselol, mbelol,kllol)), columns=['Sensor', 'R^2', 'MAE', 'RMSE', 'MBE','KL'])
```

And results:

```
  Sensor       R^2       MAE      RMSE       MBE        KL
0      I  0.803568  1.776084  5.702426  0.097944  0.044695
1      H  0.739653  2.013070  7.557870  0.102656  0.053525
2      L  0.722556  2.074596  8.054198 -0.143503  0.058237
3      G  0.696291  2.193398  8.816680  0.261528  0.062377
4      J  0.677972  2.251240  9.348475 -0.000313  0.068745
```

I have added random seed to reduce randomness of the model. I have deleted the model every loop and metric variables to avoid any overlay.

Comment: It looks like the sensors are simply in increasing order of difficulty. Did you try changing the order?

Comment: I just did and it looks you are right. I graphed the data to follow the pattern of the trends and found significant difference.

Comment: What do you mean accuracy here? There is no accuracy in regression.

Comment: Hi @Dr.Snoopy Don't you consider R^2 as an accuracy term to evaluate regression models?

Comment: Its called R^2, not accuracy.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy well, how do you measure the goodness of prediction? Should we ignore the term "accurate" and rely on evaluation metrics when speaking of regressions? Not only R^2, but RMSE or MBE. I edited my post, thanks